# Run Time Error 9 - Subscript out if range - How do I continue vba if this occurs?

Tags: excel, vba

```
''''''''''''''''''''''

ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
ActiveSheet.Cells.Pagebreak = xlPageBreakNone
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Dim Pdiv, PgCt, Pgs
PgCt = 1
Pgs = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count
Do
If Pgs = 0 Then
    Exit Do
End If

On Error Resume Next
    Cells.AutoFilter
On Error GoTo 0

Pdiv = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(PgCt).Location.Row



If Not IsEmpty(Range("B" & Pdiv).Value) Then
Cell is not empty therefore find the first occurrence of blank in Col B above this row
    Do
      Loopback until there is an empty cell in Col B
        Pdiv = Pdiv - 1
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Range("B" & Pdiv))
Set the new Page break above the empty cell
    Range("B" & Pdiv + 1).Select
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveCell
End If
PgCt = PgCt + 1
Pgs = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count
Loop Until PgCt > ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count
```

''''''''''''''''''''''''''

```
Pdiv = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(PgCt).Location.Row
```

Need help. I have been running into a Run Time Error 9 - Subscript out if range
at the above line.

I tried using on error but it does not allow the vba to continue.

ANyone knows how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Without knowing what `HPageBreaks` is (presumably a `Range` object?) it's hard to say, but potentially looks like that range is being set to 1 cell or not set at all, in which case `(1)` won't work as VBA typically uses a zero-based index

Comment: Is the PrintArea set ? If so how ?

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-receive-a-subscript-out-of-range-error-message-when-you-use-hpagebreaks-or-vpagebreaks-location-in-excel-ec4a8e22-9b58-349d-b160-f7a4f561c809

```
Sub modifyPageBreaks()
   Dim Pdiv As Long, PgCt As Long, Pgs As Long, lastc As Range, curc As Range
   
   ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
   ActiveSheet.Cells.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   PgCt = 1
   Set lastc = Me.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)
   If Me.FilterMode Then Me.ShowAllData
   If Not Selection Is Nothing Then
      If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
         Set curc = Selection
      End If
   End If
   
   lastc.Select
   Pgs = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count
   If Pgs = 0 Then Exit Sub
   
   Do
'in this loop Pgs can't be smaller from it's initial value. So the check goes before the loop
'      If Pgs = 0 Then
'          Exit Do
'      End If
       
'the next 3 lines i don't understand why exist here in loop. They just toogle filter arrows
'if have to disable filters do it once before loop (If Me.FilterMode Then Me.ShowAllData)
'        On Error Resume Next
'        Cells.AutoFilter
'        On Error GoTo 0
       
      Pdiv = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(PgCt).Location.Row
      If Not IsEmpty(Range("B" & Pdiv).Value) Then
         'Cell Is Not Empty therefore find the first occurrence of blank in Col B above this row
         Do
         'Loopback Until there Is an Empty cell in Col B
         
            Pdiv = Pdiv - 1
            If Pdiv = 0 Then Exit Do
         Loop Until IsEmpty(Range("B" & Pdiv))
         'Set the New Page break above the Empty cell
         If Pdiv > 0 Then
            ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Range("B" & Pdiv + 1)
         End If
      End If
      PgCt = PgCt + 1
      Pgs = ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count
   Loop Until PgCt > ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Count
   If Not curc Is Nothing Then curc.Select
End Sub
```